# How do I create a generic object type with two methods that take the same parameters?

Tags: typescript

I want to declare a Typescript object type `TestObj` that contains two functions, `foo` and `bar`, that take the same parameter types.

So these definitions are valid:

```
const test: TestObj = {
  foo: (a: string) => {
    console.log('foo');
  },
  bar: (b: string) => {
    console.log('bar');
  }
}

const test2: TestObj = {
  foo: (a: string, b: number) => {
    console.log('foo');
  },
  bar: (b: string) => {
    console.log('bar')
  }
}
```

But this is not, since `bar` takes a number as the first argument and `foo` takes a string:

```
const test: TestObj = {
  foo: (a: string) => {
    console.log('foo');
  },
  bar: (b: number) => {
    console.log('bar');
  }
}
```

I got close with the following:

```
type TestObj<RArgs extends any[] = any[]> = {
  foo: (...args: RArgs) => void;
  bar: (...args: RArgs) => void;
}
```

However, for it to properly typecheck, I need to explicitly specify the argument types via a type parameter:

```
const test: TestObj<[string]> = {
  foo: (a: string) => {
    console.log('foo');
  },
  bar: (b: number) => {
    console.log('bar');
  }
}
```

I'd like to find a way where Typescript will show an error without needing to duplicate the argument types via a type parameter.

Comment: One way is with a [pointless function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwDyAjAVgHgEoEEBOA5vFBAB7AQB2AJsQIaUgDaAugHxQC8UA3gFBRBUAGYB7UQC4oACgB08uoXhTcSgJRcOAN1EBLagG4BQlIqlyFSlfiIbO2vYb4BfPn2EBXSgGNgu0ZRQALZ0ANYQcIiomKpEJORUtFAMzOzS8HjeUpHI6Ng28Gwa-EJQeBDAHniBGd5GrnzeAYhQBOLUXMFhEQi5aNIlQmKSMnRSiHi6lAR2HIOlgk2U8KIANhCyq6IE0gDkw7tqRqXOADTGgqZ45ijjwJPTs7wXC0sr65vbe1eHx0KuzjUbjewCgpg63BC4Ry0QGL2G5jGUEoHiCKAgeCe81ezTWGy2O324l+LzOLyuNzuDxmmmeCyEbzxn0JPyOpJcQL4QA) to infer the type. If it's not the hot-path, probably good enough...

Comment: There is no type that expresses that two parts of a type must be identical. So you either declare `RArgs` manually, or in infer it with a function. So I think @spender's answer is the best you're going to get here.

Comment: Good to know - I hoped I was missing something, but guess not. @spender if you want to write up your response as an answer I'll accept it.